# Fetch is not happening once page refreshed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

When i open a particular page, fetching is processing successfully and data received, however for some kind of reason, once page is refreshed the fetch is not even pending its not even visible in inspect. If something seems not right kindly point it out because I already spent ages trying to figure out why this is happening.

```
state = {
  metaInfoDocs: [],
  docs: [],
  loading: false,
};

componentDidMount() {
  this.props.selectedDocsStore.clear();
  this.props.selectedDocsStore.setViewDocId(0);
  this.setState({ loading: true });
  this.props
    .fetchMetaDocs()
    .then((r) => this.setState({ metaInfoDocs: r.data, loading: false }))
    .catch((err) => {
      this.setState({ loading: false });
      errorWithMessage("Could not load documents");
    });
  this.props.eventManager.on("viewDoc", (doc) => {
    this.loadDocuments(doc.id);
  });
}
export default class CentralDocuments extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <GeneralDocPresenter
        type={"centralInformationDocuments"}
        fetchMetaDocs={() => getMetaInfoByType("central-document")}
        loadDocument={(id) => getCentralDocuments(id)}
        eventManager={new EventManager()}
        childComponents={{
          metaDocViewer: MetaInfoDocViewer,
          metaView: MetaInfoListView,
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: create this in http://www.codesandbox.io and share the full link. Just looking at half the code nobody can reproduce issue you're having.

Comment: Can you check if it's page refresh or is it simply a route change and your component is only mounted once to the page.

Comment: Everything you are doing in componentDidMount() is only going to happen when the component initially mounts.   You need to put the same code into componentDidUpdate() if you want to do it every render.   You could also use useEffect() to avoid duplicating the code block.

Comment: @FarrukhSubhani yes you right its not a refresh it's a route change , how could i proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use componentDidUpdate() lifecycle method as well. For example:

```js
updateDoc = () => {
  this.props.selectedDocsStore.clear();
  this.props.selectedDocsStore.setViewDocId(0);
  this.setState({ loading: true });
  this.props
    .fetchMetaDocs()
    .then((r) => this.setState({ metaInfoDocs: r.data, loading: false }))
    .catch((err) => {
      this.setState({ loading: false });
      errorWithMessage("Could not load documents");
    });
  this.props.eventManager.on("viewDoc", (doc) => {
    this.loadDocuments(doc.id);
  });
}

componentDidUpdate() {
  this.updateDoc()
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.updateDoc()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only using componentDidMount(), you need to also put the code into componentDidUpdate().

Something like this ..

```
state = {
  metaInfoDocs: [],
  docs: [],
  loading: false,
};

componentDidMount() {
  this.props.selectedDocsStore.clear();
  this.props.selectedDocsStore.setViewDocId(0);
  this.setState({ loading: true });
  this.props
    .fetchMetaDocs()
    .then((r) => this.setState({ metaInfoDocs: r.data, loading: false }))
    .catch((err) => {
      this.setState({ loading: false });
      errorWithMessage("Could not load documents");
    });
  this.props.eventManager.on("viewDoc", (doc) => {
    this.loadDocuments(doc.id);
  });
}

componentDidUpdate() {
  this.props.selectedDocsStore.clear();
  this.props.selectedDocsStore.setViewDocId(0);
  this.setState({ loading: true });
  this.props
    .fetchMetaDocs()
    .then((r) => this.setState({ metaInfoDocs: r.data, loading: false }))
    .catch((err) => {
      this.setState({ loading: false });
      errorWithMessage("Could not load documents");
    });
  this.props.eventManager.on("viewDoc", (doc) => {
    this.loadDocuments(doc.id);
  });
}
export default class CentralDocuments extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <GeneralDocPresenter
        type={"centralInformationDocuments"}
        fetchMetaDocs={() => getMetaInfoByType("central-document")}
        loadDocument={(id) => getCentralDocuments(id)}
        eventManager={new EventManager()}
        childComponents={{
          metaDocViewer: MetaInfoDocViewer,
          metaView: MetaInfoListView,
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

fixing the mistake